# Automatically reload Thymeleaf templates in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my Spring Boot (2.4.2) app, I have some Thymeleaf templates in the `src/main/resources/templates` directory. I have spring-boot-devtools installed which automatically reloads classes when the code changes.

I would like the Thymeleaf templates to also be automatically reloaded when they are changed. I've tried adding the following to the local application configuration

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
```

But it doesn't seem to work, i.e. the templates are loaded only on startup, so I need to restart the serve after changing them. How can I enable automatic reloading of the Thymeleaf templates?

### Update

In response to some of the comments: I run the app from IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: How you are running your application? Via Maven command or via your IDE? Also: Maybe [this commt](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/614#issuecomment-580989392) (_How to reload templates without restarting the spring boot application?_, in GitHub Issues of Thymeleaf) is interesting.

Comment: Additionally, if running in an IDE, are you sure it's automatically tracking changes and copying them to the running directory?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. **Instead of reading your templates from the built files (typically, in your /target folder), you can tell Thymeleaf to read them directly from your /resources folder.** That way, you only need to hit F5 to refresh your browser.

```
# Setup auto-reload of templates for Thymeleaf by disabling the Template Cache.
# This allows you to live-code on HTML without needing to restart the server.
spring:
  thymeleaf: # Thymeleaf
    cache: false
    mode: HTML
    encoding: UTF-8
    # change load path to resource folder instead of /target
    prefix: file:src/main/resources/templates/

  resources: # Static resources
    # change load path to resource folder instead of /target
    static-locations: file:src/main/resources/static/
    cache:
      period: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IntelliJ, you have to rebuild the project (fn + shift + 9) on mac and (ctrl + shift + f9) on windows I believe. This can be kind of annoying, there might be some built in functionality in IntelliJ, or your IDEA of choice, to just rebuild when certain files are modified.